# md-list with more then one md-secondary actions

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

In my list of objects, i can active/inactive an object. So, a icon make a active action and the other one make the inactive action, and both are in the same `md-list`.

[This is what i'm tring to do](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbxJaw?editors=101)

code:

```
<md-list ng-app="MyApp" class="listdemoListControls" ng-controller="ListCtrl">
  <md-list-item ng-repeat="message in messages" ng-click='actionOne("action one")'>
    <p>{{message.title}}</p>

    <md-button class="md-secondary md-icon-button" ng-if="!showActionThree" ng-click="actionTwo('action two')">
      Two // secondary action
    </md-button>

    <md-button class="md-secondary md-icon-button" ng-if="showActionThree" ng-click="actionThree('action three')">
      Three // third action
    </md-button>
 </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

The problem is that my `actionThree` function dos not fire.

Sounds like when i use `md-secondary` class he creates a wraper receiving my `actionTwo` function, and this function dos not change.

Is there any way of making this work?

---

[Related issue #3744](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3744)

Comment: I think you pointed the right thing. md-secondary seems to be more than a simple CSS class and look like a directive. If you try you code removing the md-secondary on both button, the thing is going pretty crazy.

Comment: Yes, actually they dont have this class in the docs, o found on `md-list` exemples. The thing is when a `ng-click` is setted into a `md-list-item`, `angular-material` wraps with a `md-button` the role thing. Thats why i need the md-secondary. To tell that, the list has a secondary action.

Comment: I would like to know if this is possible as well. For your purpose (making an item active/inactive), one button might suffice though? Pen: http://codepen.io/qvazzler/pen/pJKGMM

Comment: @WilliamS This will do the trick, but I will lose some patterns in my project. In a desktop app, will be great if i could set more then one `secondary ` action in the same `md-list-item`. I dont know if this violates some `google material` patterns from a `list` component

Comment: I understand. I will run into a similar issue eventually, but I was planning to use a context menu of sorts.

Comment: Found this! https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2595

Comment: looks like this will be a new feature in `0.11.0` version

Comment: I have the same problem. I use single md-switch for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try only one button and ternary operator, like this:

```
<md-button class="md-secondary md-icon-button" ng-click="showActionThree ? actionThree('action three') :actionTwo('action two')">
  {{showActionThree ? 'Three': 'Two'}}
</md-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need one button to display at a time, Fernando's answer is probably best. But for anyone else needing multiple buttons...

This was supposed to be fixed in 1.0.5, but then they changed their release process. You can either wait for the fix in the next stable version, or use the latest changes from `HEAD`. Even then, I suspect that they will still force secondary actions to be right-aligned.

Here's a workaround you might try. It uses `ng-mouseover` and `ng-mouseout` to track which action to execute:

```
<md-list>
  <md-list-item ng-repeat="message in messages" ng-click='rowAction(message)'>
    <p>{{message.title}}</p>

    <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-mouseover="action='two'" ng-mouseout="action=null">
      Two
    </md-button>

    <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-mouseover="action='three'" ng-mouseout="action=null">
      Three
    </md-button>
 </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

Then in the `rowAction` method, you can do something like:

```
$scope.rowAction = function (message){
    switch($scope.action){
        case 'two':
           $scope.actionTwo(message);
           break;
        case 'three':
           $scope.actionThree(message);
           break;
        default:
           $scope.actionOne(message);
    }
}
```